# model_mommy breaks django-mptt

Tags: python, django, django-testing, django-mptt, model-mommy

I'm using `model_mommy` to create instances of an `MPTTModel` in my tests, but it seems like it breaks the tree managed by mptt:

```
>>> parent = mommy.make(Category)
>>> child = mommy.make(Category, parent=parent)
>>> parent.get_descendants()
[]
```

The same without using model_mommy works properly:

```
>>> parent = Category(name=u'Parent')
>>> parent.save()
>>> child = Category(name=u'Child', parent=parent)
>>> child.save()
>>> parent.get_descendants()
[<Category: Child>]
```

I suspect that the issue is that model_mommy provides random values for `tree_id`, `lft`, `rght` and `level`, which are mandatory fields, but should be handled by MPTT.

Is there a way to tell model mommy to not fill these fields at all ? Or is there a default value for these fields that would not break MPTT's save algorithm ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out that if `lft` or `rght` have a truthy value, `MPTTModel.save` considers the node to already have been set up. Thus setting these fields to `None` is enough to fix the tree update.

I created a mommy recipe that I use everywhere in my tests, so I don't have to remember to set these fields:

```
category_recipe = Recipe(Category, lft=None, rght=None)
```

And then in the test cases: `category_recipe.make()` instead of `mommy.make(Category)`.